# Trying to do JSON.parse but it doesnt like what i am doing with a returned string from my server

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json

I was trying to return a string from my server which would be parsed into a javascript object.  I keep getting an error though when it comes to the parsing process.  I didnt know why.  Maybe you know something that i do not.

My string looks like this:

```
{{"fname":"bob","lname":"jones"},{...}}
```

What i was trying to do is something like

```
var item = JSON.parse(myString);
```

It should be making item, an array of names so i could do something like:

```
for(var i = 0; i < item.length; i++){
    alert(item[i].fname + " " + item[i].lname);
}
```

Is there something i am doing wrong?  The above was a sample, but below is actually code snippet:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader["rt_id"] != DBNull.Value && reader["rt_name"] != DBNull.Value)
    {
          t = @"{""pValue"":""{ReportType},"+reader["rt_id"]+@""",""pText"":"""+reader["rt_name"]+@"""}";
          returnContentsArray.Add(t);
    }
}
returnContents = "{" + String.Join(",",returnContentsArray.ToArray()) + "}";
return returnContents;
```

On Client:

```
var item = JSON.parse(result);
```

Comment: You should use a real JSON serializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That string is not valid JSON.  `{}` represents an object, which needs to have keys.  It seems you want an array, use `[]` instead.

```
returnContents = "[" + String.Join(",",returnContentsArray.ToArray()) + "]";
```

Comment: Ahhhh, ok.  For some reason, i was thinking that "{" was defining a set such as var x = {"a","b","c"}, like in most other languages.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: @Fallenreaper: You're welcome :-)  Yeah, JavaScript is different than other languages :-P

Answer (score 1):

You need to use correct JSON format.  It looks like the format you should be using is

```
[{"fname":"bob","lname":"jones"},{...}]
```

Which would return an array of objects.  Just make user you can validate the JSON in JSONLint of similar before trying to change up your javascript code.